# Add conditional unique check constraint?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have a table with these fields: ItemID, CategoryID, IsPrimaryCategory.

The combination of ItemID and CategoryID should always be unique and that's the easy part. But I also want a constraint to force just ItemID to be unique but *only* when IsPrimaryCategory is true.

How could I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a unique filtered index:

```
create unique index uc_MyTable_ItemID_For_PrimaryCategory
  on MyTable(ItemID)
where IsPrimaryCategory = 1
```

Comment: Awesome. Had no idea that was possible.